# Sequelize: Include.where filtering by a 'parent' Model attribute

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have two Models related, Catalog and ProductCategory. The latter has a composed PK, 'id, language_id'.
Here are the models simplified:

```
var Catalog = sequelize.define("Catalog", {
id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true
},
user_id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false
},
product_category_id: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING(7)
},
language_id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER
},  
... more stuff ...
}

var ProductCategory = sequelize.define("ProductCategory", {
id: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING(7),
  primaryKey: true
},
language_id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true
},
... more stuff ...
}

Catalog.belongsTo(models.ProductCategory, {foreignKey: 'product_category_id'});
```

I'm trying to include some info from ProductCategory table related to Catalog, but ONLY when the language_id matches.

At the moment I'm getting all the possible matches from both tables.
This is the query right now:

```
Catalog.find({where:
    {id: itemId},
    include: {
        model: models.ProductCategory, 
        where: {language_id: /* Catalog.language_id */}
    }
})
```

Is there a way to use an attribute from Catalog to filter the include where both models have the same language?

By the way, I've also tried changing the where clause, without any consecuence:

```
where: {'ProductCategory.language_id': 'Catalog.language_id'}
```

Comment: `where: {'$ProductCategory.language_id$': 'Catalog.language_id'}` this probably could have worked too

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Sequelize provides an extra operator `$col` for this case so you don't have to use `sequelize.literal('...')` (which is more a hack).

In your example the usage would look like this:

```
Catalog.find({where:
    {id: itemId},
    include: {
        model: models.ProductCategory, 
        where: {
          language_id: {$col: 'Catalog.language_id'}
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Tested it and works like a charm, thanks for the improve over my self-anser. ;)

Comment: this only returns [Object object] for me

Comment: Remember to include const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op; and you can [Op.col] instead of $col that fixed it for me

Answer (score 19):

You can try this (Especially if you are using MariaDB) -

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize'); 
const op = Sequelize.Op;

Catalog.find({where:
    {id: itemId},
    include: {
        model: models.ProductCategory, 
        where: {
          language_id: {[op.col]: 'Catalog.language_id'}
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: What is [op.col] explanation is missing

Answer (score 5):

This seems this do the trick:

```
where: {language_id: models.sequelize.literal('Catalog.language_id')}
```

Comment: where did this work? using `sequelize.literal('Sale.debt') makes this weird thing: ``Payments`.`quantity` = `val` = \'Sale.debt\'``

Comment: @dan_rocha: Replacing the inner **where** in the **Catalog.find** query I originally posted. If you share what you're trying to do I might be able to help you. The output is weird indeed, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

This block of code work for me, no need to add
`model: models.ProductCategory`  and `{[op.col]: 'Catalog.language_id'}`

```
Catalog.find({where:
    {id: itemId},
    include: {
        model: ProductCategory, 
        where: {
          language_id: 'Catalog.language_id'
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: it works because you are treating 'Catalog.language_id' as a plain string , so it is actually not working.

Answer (score -2):

Or even just try this:

```
const models = require("models directory");
    {
       model: models.ModelName,
       where: {
            column-name: column-value
         }
    }
```

Comment: The idea was to match an attribute, not a specific value. I'm afraid your response doesn't match at all the question at hand.