# how to do in Sequelize where column equal column in another table?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm using Sequlize with nodeJS, and I'm doing inner join with multiple tables in Sequelize, but in where condition I cannot find a way to add condition where table1.columnX = table2.column

Comment: By 'Include.where' - [docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll)

take a look on this examples [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052254/sequelize-include-where-filtering-by-a-parent-model-attribute)

Comment: thanks, it works, my mistake was trying in wrong "include", it worked when I tried it in the big scope "include"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
where: {
  '%included_table1.columnX%': Sequelize.col('column')
}
```

Also, you need to indicate `required: true` in the `include` option to get `INNER JOIN`.